# Views in bottomnavigationview moving to leftside

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, layout

I have bottom navigation in `MainActivity`. I have 5 tabs in the bottom navigation.
Each fragment views is shifting to the left side. My layout width is also matched, parent.

Currently, i m using LinearLayout so its look like this :
[Image  here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDCje.png)

And when I m using FrameLayout it completely moves to the left side and looks like a single column.

**Profile.xml**-LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/fragment_profile"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
tools:context="com.smiles.elearning.Profile">
</LinearLayout>
```

**Dashboard.xml**-FrameLayout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/fragment_dashboard"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/blue_500"
android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@color/white"
tools:context="com.smiles.elearning.Dashboard">
```

**Dashboard fragment**

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
   // return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);

    listSubject = v.findViewById(R.id.listSubjects);
    subjectModelList = new ArrayList<>();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, SUBJECT_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject j = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    SubjectModel subjectModel = new SubjectModel();

                    String subject = j.optString("subject");

                    subjectModel.setSubject(subject);

                    subjectModelList.add(subjectModel);
                }
                DashBoardListAdapter adapter = new DashBoardListAdapter(subjectModelList, getContext());
                listSubject.setAdapter(adapter);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    stringRequest.setShouldCache(false);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    queue.add(stringRequest);

    listSubject.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            if (i==0) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), Topics.class));
            }
        }
    });

    return v;


}
```

and it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iewFS.png)

Comment: Post your activity xml code in which you have FrameLayout content

Comment: Could you post your Fragment code

Comment: i added fragment code.. pls chk @Abhishekkumar

Comment: I think you have used Constraint layout somewhere, It is happened  when Constraint layout is used.

Comment: no it is not used anywhere

Comment: Add xml code of fragment @Anonymous

Comment: Add xml code of your parent view

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer .. I was using `FrameLayout` in my Main activity to display fragment and width of that was wrap_content. Now I changed it to `match_parent`. And works fine now.